# scala play framework reverse routing and controllers

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.3

I'm currently struggling with controllers and reverse routing. My problem is, I have a controller located in package `controllers.shop.MyController` and I'm trying to reverse route it. When I locate the controller directly in `controllers` I get the relevant options in the `routes` value. So my question is if I can get a reverse route on controllers not directly located in package `controllers`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try : controllers.shop.routes.Mycontroller.yourAction()

Comment: @curious Oh god thanks! Your my rescue! Make an answer and I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes file located at conf/routes

Add the following route

```
GET(it should be your HTTP Method)     /yourENdPoint       controllers.shop.MyController.yourAction
```

Clean run your app with command : `activator clean run`

your reverse route will be

```
controllers.shop.routes.Mycontroller.yourAction
```